# How to add a Banner in between main navigation and breadcrumb in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, menu, breadcrumbs

I have tried by using extensions but that is displayed on below the breadcrumb.

At home i have using below `{{block type="trbanner/trbanner" name="trbanner" template="trbanner/trbanner.phtml"}}` and it works. Then please help.

Comment: can please show me ,your banner extension layout file... it require either wise question goes to closed.

Comment: there is no layout file.only code that is inserted into the home page.the code is {{block type="trbanner/trbanner" name="trbanner" template="trbanner/trbanner.phtml"}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create local.xml at `app/design/frontend/your Package/your template/layout/` and put the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="breadcrumbs">
            <block type="trbanner/trbanner" name="btbanner" template="trbanner/trbanner.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

and then on breadcrumbs.phtml file and  the top of all the code  call the banner

```
<?php  echo $this->getChildHtml('btbanner')?>
```

Comment: but still not working..

Comment: mistake myself.. <?php  echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs')?> to <?php  echo $this->getChildHtml('btbanner')?>